# python tic tac toe scoreboard not updating

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

they closed this question so I can't delete it because people "answered it" whatever

The problem is that the scoreboard isn't updating when the game ends; it's only shown at the beginning.

How do we fix this? Do we need to implement a loop, or rearrange parts of our code?

Here is the code:

```
import time

print("Tic-Tac-Toe Game ")
print("Please Wait...")
time.sleep(3)

def game_winner(player):
    if Game==Draw:    
        print("Game Draw")
        return 'D'
    elif Game==Win:    
      player-=1    
      if player != 0:    
        print("Player 1 Won") 
        return   
      else:    
        print("Player 2 Won") 
        return
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I just ran your code and managed to get through one game correctly. You are right that upon completion of one game, entering "yes" does not show the scoreboard correctly.

You already have your code set up as various functions, which is good. What you might want to do is have a `play(board, player:str, move:int)` function that accepts the player and the respective move and updates the board each time. You will need a modified `while` loop, because a draw, win or lose condition would end the game. The `play()` function should just keep track of the current player, and switch between 0 and 1, respectively as each move is played.

You might have something like:

```py
# Set player 0 to start, X
start_player = 0
while not checkGameEnd():
    # Take player input
    move = int(input("Where do you want to move?"))
    # Make the play
    play(board, start_player, move)
    # Print the board
    printBoard()
    # Change player
    start_player = 1 if start_player is 0 else 1
# Game should end here
printScores()
playAgain()
```

This is sort of pseudo-code, but you can modify the logic as per your usecase.

Answer (score 1):

The scoreboard printed at the end for me when I responded `n` to the question `'Do you want to play again?'`.

However, it showed 0-0 because the code doesn't update the scores. I think you want to add the following in the `game_winner` function:

```
elif Game ==Win:    
    player -= 1    
    if player != 0:
        print("Player 1 Won")
        score_board[player1] += 1
        return
    else:
        print("Player 2 Won")
        score_board[player2] += 1
        return
```

Also, you'll need to move the `game_winner(player)` function call at the end outside of the `while` loop so that it only called once.

Answer (score 1):

you need to modify the `score_board` variable at the end of each match, so that when you print it at the end of the game it will be updated with the final score,to do so you can modify your `game_winner` function like this:

```
def game_winner(player):
    if Game==Draw:    
        print("Game Draw")
        score_board[player1] += 0.5
        score_board[player2] += 0.5
        return 'D' 
    elif Game ==Win:    
        player -= 1    
        if player != 0:
            print("Player 1 Won")
            score_board[player1] += 1
            return
        else:
            print("Player 2 Won")
            score_board[player2] += 1
            return
```